# The command `grep -Ilri foo . | xargs grep -i bar` works only if the resulting path has no space

Tags: bash, grep, macos, xargs

To find all the files that have the word `foo` in it, and also the word `bar` in it, we can use

```bash
grep -Ilri foo . | xargs grep -i bar
```

(which is case insensitive and exclude binary files)... however, if the file path is like

`/Users/myusername/Text Files`

then it won't work, because now the `xargs` portion becomes

```bash
grep -i bar /Users/myusername/Text Files
```

but in reality it needs to be

```bash
grep -i bar "/Users/myusername/Text Files"
```

or

```bash
grep -i bar /Users/myusername/Text\ Files
```

How can it be made to work?  (it is on macOS Monterey).

Comment: Don't use `grep` to **find** files, there's a perfectly good tool with a very obvious name for doing that. Use `grep` to **G**lobally match a **R**egular **E**xpression in a file and **P**rint the result (once again there is a big hint in the name of the tool what it is designed to do well).

Comment: Strictly speaking `grep -i foo` finds the files that have the `foo` *string* in it, even if it's only part of a word (like in sea**foo**d).

Comment: Even more strictly speaking `grep -i foo` prints the lines from files that contain strings that match the *regexp* `foo` which matters if `foo` can contain regexp metachars.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your `grep` supports GNU's `-Z` / `--null` option to delimit file names with null bytes (FreeBSD's only supports the long `--null` variant), and your `xargs` supports the `-0` option (also `--null` with some) to use the null byte as input item separator, you can use those to handle file names safely:

```
grep -Ilri --null foo . | xargs -0 grep -i bar
```

If your `grep` and `xargs` don’t support these non-standard options (but then again, neither `-r` nor `-I` are standard either), you can use `find`:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -Iiq foo {} \; -exec grep -iq bar {} \; -print
```

This looks for files starting in the current directory, and for each file it finds, runs `grep` to determine whether it contains “foo”, and if it does, runs `grep` again to determine whether it contains “bar”, and if it does, prints its name.

This isn’t efficient but it works safely.

Answer (score 4):

To "find all the files that have the word `foo` in it, and also the word `bar` in it" using mandatory POSIX tools on any Unix box (untested):

```
find . -type f -exec \
    awk '
        FNR==1 { x=y=0 }
        { $0 = tolower($0) }
        /foo/ { x=1 }
        /bar/ { y=1 }
        x && y { hits[FILENAME]; nextfile }
        END { for (fname in hits) print fname }
    ' {} +
```

or if you prefer:

```
find . -type f -exec \
    awk '
        FNR==1 { x=y=0 }
        { $0 = tolower($0) }
        /foo/ { x=1 }
        /bar/ { y=1 }
        x && y && !seen[FILENAME]++ { print FILENAME; nextfile }
    ' {} +
```

In both cases above we use `nextfile` for efficiency in awks that support it but also write code to ensure that even in awks that don't support it we won't print the same file name multiple times.

The above assumes you don't care about matching on substrings or regexp vs string matches.

Comment: My preference would be to print matching filenames immediately: `print FILENAME; nextfile`.

Comment: interesting solution... I suppose if we use awk, we also can use Ruby or NodeJS... NodeJS's version might be as simple as `/foo/.test(s) && /bar/.test(s)` but I don't know how to get the file content into `s`

Comment: @D.BenKnoble it's not quite that simple but I added the code to print file names immediately if you prefer. Either way you end up with an array of file names.

Comment: @nonopolarity depends how clear, simple, and portable you want your code to be, among other things. `awk` is a mandatory POSIX tool so, just like `grep` and `find`, it must exist on every Unix box and it processes text simply and extremely efficiently since that's the one thing it's designed to do. I also used code that'll work in all `awk` and `find` variants, not just GNU as in the `grep` commands in your question (for `-I` and `-r`) and the currently accepted answer.